# How to add a uiviewcontroller when the app is opened and i receive a push?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, presentmodalviewcontroller

Hello everyone I receive push notification and if the app is active, I give the user an alertview whether he/she wants to view notification or not. If the user selects "yes" then I present a modal and all these are done in the app delegate.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController presentModalViewController:EO animated:NO];
```

So far everything works fine, but when I am in the app and I am on an already presented modal I get the following warning :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ABCViewcontroller: 0x201f27f0>  on <SWViewController: 0x1f58c330> which is already presenting <UINavigationController: 0x201d3050>
```

And i dont see the window presented modally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A controller can only have one modal presented at a time. A potential quick fix is to dismiss a potential modal first, before showing the new one:

```
// Dismiss
[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

// Then present
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: All right thanks :) :). Is there any alternatives to presentmodal instead.. Like addview?

Comment: Yeah you have other options, for sure. For instance, you could set the window's root controller to whatever `EO`is. Kind of depends on your UX. For times when I'm shifting the user to a totally different part of the experience, I like to 'tear down' the current context by resetting the controller stack on a main nav controller (which is the window's root)